# max_clients limit reached error on tornado-botocore server

Tags: python, tornado, boto, botocore

I've developed a Tornado server using the tornado-botocore package for interacting with Amazon SQS service.
When I'm trying to load test the server i get the following log:
[simple_httpclient:137:fetch_impl] max_clients limit reached, request queued. 10 active, 89 queued requests.
I assume it's from the ASyncHTTPClient used by the botocore package.
I've tried to set the max_clients to an higher number but with no success:

```
    def _connect(self, operation):
    sqs_connection = Botocore(
        service='sqs', operation=operation,
        region_name=options.aws_sqs_region_name,
        session=session)
    sqs_connection.http_client.configure(None, defaults=dict(max_clients=5000))
```

what am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`configure` is a class method that must be called before an `AsyncHTTPClient` is created: `tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient.configure(None, max_clients=100)`.

The log message does not indicate an error (it's logged at `debug` level). It's up to you whether it's appropriate for this service to respond to load by using more connections or queuing things up. 5000 connections for a single application process seems like too much to me.

Comment: any recommendation for a max_clients value?

Comment: There are too many variables to give a specific recommendation but it's rare in my experience to need more than 100.